# Webapp built with phonegap isn't visible in tablet

Tags: cordova, tablet

i made a webapp with dreamweaver cs6+ phonegap, and it works great on the mobile phones i tested. The problem comes when i tested it on my tablet.

The white buttons I used become invisible. You just see the button's border, not the content in the button. My webapp works is a test, and if the user can't see the options to choose, it's a very big problem.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you provide some specifics on how the buttons are constructed?

Comment: Also it would be beneficial to provide specifics as to the devices you tested on.

Comment: I tested it on a Smartq 10 tablet with Android 2.2. May be that's the reason? Greetings. The buttons were made using code from here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.1/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html